# "Use of undeclared identifier 'PFLoginViewController'? --Parse import

Tags: xcode, import, parse-platform

I've been trying to import the Parse login and Sign Up view controllers, but keep receiving the same error. I have successfully imported parse in general with my project, but for some reason I am getting the above error when I try to add the following to my view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    
    if (![PFUser currentUser]) { // No user logged in
        // Create the log in view controller
        PFLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
        [logInViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate
        
        // Create the sign up view controller
        PFSignUpViewController *signUpViewController = [[PFSignUpViewController alloc] init];
        [signUpViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate
        
        // Assign our sign up controller to be displayed from the login controller
        [logInViewController setSignUpController:signUpViewController];
        
        // Present the log in view controller
        [self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to add that I have imported "#import <Parse/Parse.h>" successfully in the .h file of that viewcontroller.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of issues and potential issues.

First, be sure to

```
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>
```

Second, your View Controller needs to conform to a couple protocols.

```
<PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate>
```

Third, you're mixing code for **signup** and **login** view controllers. Try unifying those. I highly suggest starting with a sample project provided by Parse before writing your own code.

Comment: Had same issue upgrading to Parse 7.1.1 that is using Swift, not Objective C. So just import ParseUI within the class using the PF login controller.